# Why powershell command delete my nuget packages which the same command requires?

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, entity-framework-core, nuget

I run this command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB-Name;Integrated Security=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

in PowerShell in the same directory as my project. I get an error that I need the following packages:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

I installed them and run the same command again. Then my packages were uninstalled and I get the same error.

Can you tell me what the problem could be? I am on Windows 7 if that matters

Comment: Did you compile on same machine that you are currently using?  If not did you deploy applicaiton?  It your connection string in c# same as powershell?

Comment: @jdweng I am on the same machine but I am wondering why such a command is deleting my packages

Comment: Are they 64 bit or 32 bit?  Check date of exe file in Debug and Release folders and see which one is getting updated.  Also check if the are other folders in the project bin folder.

Comment: check your dot-net core, ef-core, and ef core cmd line versions. maybe it is version conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the packages from nuget in Visual Studio. Now I tried to do that via powershell and I succeeded. I've no idea why that happened.